# How can I ORDER BY in traditional 'time' increments, a value string, ex: "10:00 AM", from a database entry that is NOT in date() format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date, datetime

More details:
I am using PHP 5.4 on localhost (XAMPP) with PHPMyAdmin. I have a DB with two relevant tables, `users` and `customers`.

I want to be able to order and display a `users` -> `customers` in proper timeline within potential 15 minute intervals, ie: `'10:15 AM', '10:30 AM'... '12:45 PM', '1:30 PM'` etc. I have researched this and tried several different approaches that do not seem to get the results I am looking for.

There is a `users` table, this is a validated logged user who has the ability to add their own customers. The unique `id` for the user is stored in a column on the `customers` table. This allows me to order by user from the `customers` table using that column.

The `customers` table has a column `route_time`, this is a varchar holding a regular string. The time comes from an array holding time starting at `"7:00 AM"` and continues in 15 minute intervals until it gets to `"6:45 PM"`. This is POSTED through a form select option as 'route_time'.

I am trying to get the proper time format, but get issues with meridiem and double digit hours, like 10, 11 and 12.

I have managed to work out the meridiem issue doing the following, but I am sure there is a more efficient way as I am a novice PHP coder.

```
$monday="";
$monday1=""; 
$mon = "
        SELECT *
        FROM `customers`
        WHERE `user_id`='".$uid."' 
        AND `route_day` = 'Monday'
        ORDER BY CAST(`route_time` AS UNSIGNED), `route_time`;
        ";
 $monResults = $cust->db->query($mon);
    if($monResults->num_rows){
        while($rows = $monResults->fetch_assoc()){
            $time=SUBSTR($rows['route_time'],5,3);
            if(trim($time) == 'AM'){
                $monday .= '<div style="padding-top:5px;" class="row"><a title="Edit this customer." href="?editCust=Y&cid='.$rows['cid'].'">'.$rows['cfname'].' '.$rows['clname'].'</a></div>';
                $monday .= '<div class="row" style="color:red;"><small>'.$rows['route_time'].'</small></div>';
                $monday .= '<div class="row"><small>'.$rows['cstreet'].'</small></div>';
                $monday .= '<div class="row"><small>'.$rows['ccity'].' '.$rows['cstate'].', '.$rows['czip'].'</small></div>';
            }elseif(trim($time) == 'PM'){
                $monday1 .= '<div style="padding-top:5px;" class="row"><a title="Edit this customer." href="?editCust=Y&cid='.$rows['cid'].'">'.$rows['cfname'].' '.$rows['clname'].'</a></div>';
                $monday1 .= '<div class="row" style="color:red;"><small>'.$rows['route_time'].'</small></div>';
                $monday1 .= '<div class="row"><small>'.$rows['cstreet'].'</small></div>';
                $monday1 .= '<div class="row"><small>'.$rows['ccity'].' '.$rows['cstate'].', '.$rows['czip'].'</small></div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Strings with "1:00 AM" = 7 whereas, strings with "10:00 AM" = 8. This is the `$time=SUBSTR($rows['route_time'],5,3);`, if I pull from the 5th string and go 3, I can then use the `trim($time)` function to remove extra white space from the beginning of meridiem that comes from 7 string values. Then use if/else for arguments.

Then I call on it using the following code:

```
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Monday</h4><?php echo $monday.$monday1; ?></div>
<?php 
    }
    if($tueResults->num_rows){
?>
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Tuesday</h4><?=$tuesday.$tuesday1?></div>
<?php 
    } 
    if($wedResults->num_rows){
?>
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Wednesday</h4><?=$wednesday.$wednesday1?></div>
<?php 
    } 
    if($thursResults->num_rows){
?>
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Thursday</h4><?=$thursday.$thursday1?></div>
<?php 
    } 
    if($friResults->num_rows){
?>
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Friday</h4><?=$friday.$friday1?></div>
<?php 
    }
    if($satResults->num_rows){                  
?>
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Saturday</h4><?=$saturday.$saturday1?></div>
<?php 
    } 
    if($sunResults->num_rows){                  
?>
<div class='col-md-2 text-left'><h4><small><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></small> Sunday</h4><?=$sunday.$sunday1?></div>
```

This orders the merdiem properly, the issue I am having is that I am unable to sort 12: before 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in PM. I also get a weird issue with 10:00 AM orders AFTER 10:15 AM, this is intermittent as well, very weird. I am unable to post a photo as this is my first post on stackoverflow and do not have the proper reputation to add a photo yet =/. Here is a link to a hosted photo on my test server website. http://dalelandry.com/img//ex.PNG

I am also curious to know if I should scrap this approach and use a `date()` or `datetime()` method of holding customers specific `route_times`. I also have a column similar as `route_day` that is also a VARCHAR that comes from an array select option as well. I have no issues with it though. Should I adopt a `date()` based approach here? Are there more options for ORDER BY in regards to `date()` as per 12:00 PM comes before 12:45 PM or should I stick with the string option? I appreciate any advice or assistance! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't choose to use `datetime` or `timestamp` type for your `route_time` column?  There may be a workaround, but it would require a bit of work, and could be avoided through better table design.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Inexperience I guess... I am starting to think the work will be well spent rather than scratching my head trying to hack together fixes or work around for something that should seem so simple.

Comment: If you insist on storing the `route_time` in a `varchar` your best bet would be to do the sorting with `PHP` using the [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function.

Comment: UPDATE: I have come to the conclusion that using date() & datetime() is far superior than trying to hack together string value arrays to deal with time and day of week as a string when it is built in as a function already.

I will update my DB for the two entries I need, one a `date('l')` for the day of the week and the other `datetime('m-d-y @ g:i A')` for the date and time. I will be able to use different DateTime functions to pull the data I need and display it the way I need from DB from there. 

Thank you Tim and mrun for the thoughtful input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that using `date()` & `datetime()` is far superior than trying to hack together string value arrays to deal with time and day of week as a string when it is built in as a function already. I will update my DB for the two entries I need, one a `date('l')` for the day of the week and the other `datetime('m-d-y @ g:i A')` for the date and time. I will be able to use different DateTime functions to pull the data I need and display it the way I need from DB from there. Thank you Tim and mrun for the thoughtful input!

Comment: Update: I have found that if you save your date() values as timedate, queries work flawlessly in incremented time standard.

Comment: I can then bring my timedate value from the database and convert it using `date('h:i A', $timedatevalue)`
`$dt = strtotime('Friday');`

`echo $dt; outputs: '1490943600'`
Then on call back `date('l', $dt); outputs: 'Friday'`

Monday = `1491202800`
Tuesday = `1491289200`
Wednesday = `1491375600`
etc... 
Each timedate value increments higher in parallel with its preceding value. Problem solved.